# Scrollable TextView with onClickListener - Click is triggered too easily

Tags: android, onclick, textview, scrollable

I make a TextView scrollable via

```
setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

and I make it clickable via

```
setOnClickListener(...)
```

which works as it should (clicking the TextView causes it to slide down, and scrolling is enabled as long as it has not been clicked)

BUT the click event is triggered too easily - often, the click is triggered after the user has scrolled (but not always). Clearly, the click-tolerance is too low - after a user has scrolled, the tolerance should be higher.

My question: **Is there a way to increase the tolerance for the onClick event?**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it better to set `View.setOnTouchListener' and check manually if there was a click o not.